# get full array from config files in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, config

I did a lot of search for my problem but I did not get anything ..

in codeigniter when I use config files I do that :

my_config.php :

```
$config['my_title'] = ' My Title Here ' ;
$config['color']    = ' red ' ;
```

I can retrieve it like this :

```
$this->load->config('my_config', TRUE );
$data['my_title'] = $this->config->item('my_title', 'my_config');
```

My question is : How can I get the full array to deal with it ?

I want the $config as an array to do something like this :

```
 foreach($config as $key=>$val){
          $data[$key] = $val ;
        }
```

so I do not have to write all my variables that in config file like this :

```
$data['my_title'] = $this->config->item('my_title', 'my_config');
$data['color'] = $this->config->item('color', 'my_config');
```

and so on ..

sorry for my broken English !

thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While this is undocumented, and might break in future releases, you can access the main config array by:

```
$config = $this->config->config;
```

Comment: thank you very much Joseph , but this give me that data in main config.php .. I want to use data that in my custom file (my_config.php) ? thanks again ( I'm trying to get it by myself right now )

Comment: aha , sorry joseph I did not notice  .. I get all data that in config.php and in my_config.php .. it's very nice now , thanks again :)

Comment: Something to note, if you want a certain config file you would do: `$redis = $this->config->config['redis']`

Answer (score 3):

```
    $config=$this->load->config('my_config', TRUE );
    $config = $this->config;
    $my_config=$config->config['my_config'];

    echo"<pre>";print_r($my_config);
```

It may help you..

Answer (score 0):

If you get multidimentional array from config files in Codeigniter
 then 
In application/config/config.php

$config['name']='array_name';

In Model or Controller file

$variable = $this->config->item('name');

var_dump($variable);